# Is it possible to install Ubuntu from within CentOS 7 VPS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, vps

My VPS hosting provider's panel is bugged, and I'm stuck with CentOS 7, can't re-image to another linux distro (contacting support hasn't been successful, they tell me it's fixed and close my ticket, and it's not fixed).

Now I have ssh and web console access to the CentOS system, is it possible to install Ubuntu or any other linux distro just using these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely is possible.  Archlinux has [this howto](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux) that should illustrate how to do it with their system, and you should be able to deduce how to go about doing it from others by reading.  [Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en) has instructions as well, though theirs seems more geared to just running it in a chroot, or installing to a separate hard drive for dualbooting.  Likewise, it can be tailored to do a full replacement if you wish.  And, for your specified Ubuntu preference, the link is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/linux-upgrade.html)

#### Basically, the process is to

1. Create a a directory to build the system in,
2. Install necessary basic tools to get the ball rolling (depending on what method you use, this can often involve a C compiler, but doesn't need to),
3. `chroot` to the build environment,
4. Install the rest of your system,
5. Bootstrap the new system, and lastly
6. `rsync` the build chroot to your root directory.

The specifics of this vary quite a bit from distro to distro, but the core principles are the same.

It is worth noting that if you're okay with running the system out of containers, you can actually go ahead and install as many distros as you'd like (that you have space for reasonably) simultaneously using tools like `lxc` or `docker` (or even just plain `chroot`).  As that is outside the scope of the question though, I'll leave it for you to look into on your own.

Comment: Thanks for writing all that to get me started on the right path.